# WooCommerce - Get paypal transaction details after checkout

Tags: woocommerce

I need to develop a woocommerce fraud prevention plugin which uses the data provided by the api.

I need to know is there a way to get the AVS, CCV and paypal information such as address verified or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to request the PayPal REST API. Implement it in `woocommerce_after_checkout_form`

[Paypal User Information](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#get-user-information)

[Paypal CVV Information](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#store-a-credit-card)

In the same page you can get details about AVS and other details.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to the woocommerce stuff. How could I get the paypal transaction ID or similar to use their API.